# RegEx to get everything except letters,spaces, ', and -

Tags: python, regex

Is there a more simplified regular expression to match anything that is not a letter, hypen, space, or apostrophe?

This is the regex I was using...

```
[^\w\s'-]|\d|_|\xa0
```

It's working, I was just curious if there was a more simplified expression

Comment: You mean "space" rather than "whitespace", correct?  `\s` matches more than a space.

Comment: Note that `\w` matches `_` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[^a-zA-Z-' ]
```

Matches everything except letters A-z, hyphens, spaces and apostrophes

Answer (score 1):

`\w` already includes `\d` and `_`. So the simplest regex will be:

```
[^\w\s\-']
```

Comment: But that would not match a digit, which it sounds like the pattern should match based on the OP's description.

Comment: Yea @J0e3gan is correct. I need it to match to everything but a letter, space, hyphen, and apostrophe

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern...

```
[^a-z- ']
```

...is simpler and should do what you want with case-insensitivity set:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'[^a-z- \']', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str1 = u"9"
test_str2 = u"["
test_str3 = u"_"

re.search(p, test_str1)
re.search(p, test_str2)
re.search(p, test_str3)
```

Mirroring Maroun Maroun's comment, `\w` matches `_`; it also matches `0-9`: so saying "not `a-z` or `A-Z` *or* `0-9` *or* `_`" with `[^\w`...`]`...then saying "`0-9` or `_`" with `|\d|_` is a bit confusing and needlessly complicating.

Same with `\s`, as it matches more than a space (specifically a carriage return, new line, tab, or form feed), which does not jive with wanting to match "anything that is not...*a space*...": given your description then, use a literal  over the `\s` character class.